# Are Sharing Settings of Relationship fields retrievable by Schema or Metadata/Tooling API?

Tags: apex, metadata-api, relationships, tooling-api, schema

Is there a way to find out in Apex code if on of the two radio options is set in an Org?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.200.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_fields_describe.htm#apex_methods_system_fields_describe

```
Volume__c.mdr_Volume__c.getDescribe().isWriteRequiresMasterRead();
```

Take a look at the above article .The field describe has a method iswriterequiresmasterRead() .This should indicate you what you need.